# How to add an Angular property to an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to know how to add to an html button the property `(click) = function()` of angular through Javascript.

Note: I cannot modify the HTML, I can only add the property through JavaScript.

I tested with **addEventListener** and it works by adding the common JavaScript `click = "function"` event, but not the `(click)` of Angular.

I attach the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-iframe',
  templateUrl: './iframe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./iframe.component.scss']
})
export class IframeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  capture() {         
      let button = document.getElementById('cancelButton').addEventListener('(click)', this.cancel.bind(Event));
  }

  cancel() {
      console.log('Cancelled');
  }
}
```

And the HTML here:

```
<div class="row text-center pad-md">
  <button id="acceptButton" mat-raised-button color="primary">OK!</button>
  <button id="cancelButton" mat-raised-button>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you cannot modify the HTML, you will have to use `addEventListener("click", this.cancel.bind(this))`. Is it a problem?

Comment: Why cannot you change the HTML?

Comment: i've tried with addEventListener("click", this.cancel.bind(this)) and it aplies the 'common' click property of vanilla Javascript, but not the (click) reagarding to the Angular directive.

Comment: And I cannot modify the HTML because it is retrieving from an external URL

Comment: Firstly, is the iframe loading a page from the same domain?

Comment: It is, but only in order to try it, the real implementation will provide a form from a external domain

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the author, the event need to be attached dynamically to the DOM element that is created after a request, so you can use [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)
to listen for the click event. Your code should look like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-iframe',
  templateUrl: './iframe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./iframe.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  capture() {         
      const button = document.getElementById('cancelButton');
      console.log(button);
      this.renderer.listen(button, 'click', this.cancel);
  }

  cancel() {
      console.log('Cancelled');
  }
}
```

There's a functional example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-event-bind).

Comment: Yes I tried that before, and it works in order to add the "common" click event of HTML to the object. But as I said before, I need to append the (click) directive of angular, not the click event of HTML. Because the function is in the component of Angular and I cannot access to these function from the common click of HTML.

Comment: You're correct! I've edited the answer, try that instead.